# mySql different between 2 allies

Tags: mysql

im query mysql data for mismatch 2 different table data, i already trying getting data on picture bellow. now i need to compare sell_qty and sold_qty allies.

please check out this query

```
 SELECT 
purchase_lines.`product_id`,
(SELECT SUM(`quantity`) FROM `purchase_lines` 
WHERE transaction_sell_lines.product_id = purchase_lines.product_id GROUP BY product_id LIMIT 1 ) as purchase_qty,
(SELECT SUM(`quantity`) FROM `transaction_sell_lines` 
WHERE transaction_sell_lines.product_id = purchase_lines.product_id GROUP BY product_id LIMIT 1 ) as sell_qty,
(SELECT SUM(`quantity_sold`) FROM `purchase_lines` 
WHERE transaction_sell_lines.product_id = purchase_lines.product_id GROUP BY product_id LIMIT 1 ) as sold_qty,
variation_location_details.qty_available as avaiable_qty
FROM 
`purchase_lines`, 
variation_location_details,
transaction_sell_lines
WHERE 
purchase_lines.product_id = variation_location_details.product_id
AND
variation_location_details.product_id = transaction_sell_lines.product_id
GROUP BY 
variation_location_details.product_id
```

[image]

I need to different between on where clause

> **sell_qty != sold quantity**

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ( {your query} ) AS data WHERE sell_qty <> sold_qty`

Comment: Thanks Akina, its worked. do you tell me how to update sold quantity from available qty or sell qty column.

Comment: `UPDATE table JOIN ( {query} ) AS data ON {condition} SET table.column = data.column`